# How can rename a google account without the original account create alias?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to rename a Google account in my domain but when i rename the original account this email don't go to Alias, it is possible?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible

- You need to use the method [Users:Update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update)
- Specify as `userKey` the current email of the user
- Provide in request body th new primary email

```
{
  "primaryEmail": "new@yourdomain.com"
}
```

**Now the primaryEmail is updated, and the old primary Email automatically becomes an alias.**

If you want to remove the old email completely, you need to remove it from the alias with [Users.aliases: delete](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/aliases/delete).

For this:

- Specify the new email as `userKey`
- Specify the old email you want to delete as `alias`